# How to toggle class on click to animate an AJAX page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm building a simple practice project where each page is loaded via AJAX and would present a fadeIn, fadeOut transition using CSS animation opacity.

The problem is that the `addClass` and `removeClass` are not being executed.

JS (JQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// $('.mainSplash').css('height',$(window).height() - 60);

$(".aboutBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageTitle =  $(this).text();
    var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');

    changePage(pageUrl, true, pageTitle);
}); // click

function changePage(url, bool, pageTitle){
    $('#wrapper').addClass('animate');

    loadContent(url, bool, pageTitle);
}

function loadContent(url, bool, pageTitle){
    $.ajax({
        url: './' + url,
        type: 'get',
        contentType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
                // load content
                $('#content').html(data);

                // Change url
                if(url != window.location){
                    window.history.pushState({path: url}, pageTitle, url);
                }
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#wrapper').removeClass('animate');
        }
    });
}

});
```

[**Here's the full Codepen project example**](https://codepen.io/billcastillo/project/editor/AnnYEO/#0)

Comment: your codepen seems to be working fine. `animate` class is added and removed correctly. Where are you facing problem?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj oh I see, it is being added! But it's too fast that the animation isn't even done yet when the class is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having issues with the animation being removed before it finishes and thus it is not visible. You would want to listen for when the animation event ends, and remove the class in the callback there (if it really needs to be removed) instead of removing it when the page is done loading.